# Dynamic headers in the CSV using Dictwriter

Tags: python, csv

My existing code writes a list of dictionaries to a CSV using `csv.DictWriter`. But a new case came in to picture today, that dictionary keys are varying in the Third party API response i.e Some responses are coming with additional keys in the dictionary or sometime some keys are missing in the response dictionary.

We want a single CSV with all the headers as dictionary keys and associatin the CSV, and all the corrested values for those headers should be the corresponding dictionary value

*UPDATE* I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to store all the results in the memory. I'm fetching around 1300 API calls that uses 128MB on AWS lambda. If I store it in a list (1300 calls*25 items per batch= 32500 dictionaries), definitely It will use more than 512MB memory of Lambda.

eg. Sample Response Data ( Result of `response.get('data', [])`):

```
 [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 3}, {"b": 5, "c": 3, "d":3}, {"a": 22, "b": "25", 8, 9} ... etc]
```

In this case My CSV should be:

```
a      b      c      d
1      2             3
5             3      3
22     25     8      9
```

eg.

```
# Fetch Third party API data in batches 25 records/batch
def fetch_api_data(self, url, payload):
    while True:
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload).json()
        yield response.get('data', [])
        if 'next_page_url' not in response:
              break
        url = response['next_page_url']


def update_recs_to_csv(self, url, payload):
    responses = fetch_api_data(url, payload)
    first_25_rows = next(responses)
    first_row = first_25_rows[0]
    keys = first_row.keys() 
    with open("output.csv", "w") as output_file:
         dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
         dict_writer.writeheader()
         dict_writer.writerow(first_row)
         for row_dict in responses:
             dict_writer.writerow(row_dict)   #-- This row_dict comes with different (varying) keys
```

Comment: The simple way would be that the total list of keys is a static list known at startup time, in order not to have to browse all the dictionaries to build it. If it is not possible, you have to either load everything in memory, store it on disk, or if it makes sense browse the list of dictionaries twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a simplified example let's say your response is:

```
response = [{"a": 1, "b": 2, "d": 3}, {"b": 5, "c": 3, "d":3}, {"a": 22, "b": "25"}]
```

I would first compute the union of the keys present in the response:

```
common_keys = {k for r in response for k in r}
```

now I would just write the dictionary with those keys as field names. There's a default value (empty) when the key isn't in a particular dictionary:

```
import csv

with open("out.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    cw = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=sorted(common_keys),restval="",delimiter="\t")
    cw.writeheader()
    cw.writerows(response)
```

I get:

```
a       b       c       d
1       2               3
        5       3       3
22      25
```

EDIT: this works only if `response` is a `list` so you'd have to convert to `list` first with:

```
response = list(response)
```

If this takes too much memory, then, since the union of the keys cannot be computed without having iterated through the whole list, the only alternative is to dump the response lines in a file (ex: 1 `json` dict per line) while computing the union of the keys, then read that again to create the `csv` file.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but in this case I will have to fetch all the responses and will have to store it in a new list. otherwise once I fetch the `common_keys` my response will be exhausted as it is a generaor

Comment: just do `response = list(response)` and you're okay

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre - Thanks for your efforts. I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to store it. I'm fetching around 1300 API calls that uses 128MB  on AWS lambda. If I store it in a list (1300 calls *25 items per batch= 32500 dictionaries) , definitely It will use more than 512MB memory

Comment: that should be an hypothesis in your question. I'll think about it

Comment: Yeah, agree. I tried to write the question with minimal description. I will update the query

Comment: that said, it's not possible to predict the union of the keys without having iterated through the list first... you could try to dump to disk using `json` while composing the list of the keys, and then read this json again to write your csv file.